# OAUTH 2 not working on "standalone" HTML5 app vrs web app

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, homescreen

I have a web app eg  www.webapp.com that uses Google's OAUTH2 (gapi.authorize) (OAUTH2) to sign in users.  It works from the desktop and mobile devices as long as I use the browser to navigate to the site.

**PROBLEM**: I can install it to the (eg "Add to Homescreen" on Android).  But when I run it from the homescreen, the authentication/consent screen gets stuck on  a blank page and a "connecting" message. My manifest.json file has **display: standalone**

I have to manually close the popup, and use the "Back" button on the phone to get back to the login screen.  The response 
token etc.  are there as expected.  Why is the popup screen **not closing**?   How can it be forced to close without user intervention?